# Magento Soap API Add Bundle Product to Cart

Tags: php, magento, soap

I'm trying to create an order with Magento SOAP API v1 and having issue when adding bundled products to the cart. I'm able to get an order through correctly with simple products but I'm confused about adding bundled products.

```
// The Products Array with Bundle
$products = array(
        array(
            "product_id" => "38914",
            "qty" => "1",
            "bundle_option" => array(
                "18194" => "20360",
            ),
            "related_product" => null,
            "bundle_qty" => array("20360" => "1"),
            "options" => array(
                "0" => array(
                    "key" => "3328",
                    "value" => "4494",
                ),
                "1" => array(
                    "key" => "3329",
                    "value" => null,
                ),
                "2" => array(
                    "key" => "3339",
                    "value" => null,
                ),

            )
        )
    );

// Get an API session
$client = new \SoapClient('magentoinstallation/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl');
$session = $client->login('user', 'password');

//Create the Cart
$cart = $client->call( $session, 'cart.create');

// add the products
$resultCartProductsAdd = $client->call( $session, "cart_product.add", array(     $cart, $products ) );
```

I've tried many different formats and getting errors

```
Selected required options are not available

Please specify product option(s).
```

Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try change "options" to "bundle_option" here http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/programatically-add-bundle-product-to-cart-n-magento/   You have PHP API method but array should be similar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out a way to add a bundle product to cart via SOAP.

The values within the key `bundle_option` must be the ids of the models for the options (bundle/selection) (not the product ids). The keys must be the id for the option (I assume that's already correct in your example)

```
$products = array(
    array(
        "product_id" => "38914",
        "qty" => "1",
        "bundle_option" => array(
            "18194" => "20360", // <-- THE VALUE MUST BE THE ID OF THE CORRESPONDING "bundle/selection" MODEL, INSTEAD OF THE PRODUCT'S ID
        ),
// ...
);
```

Also the key for the bundle quantities should be `bundle_option_qty` instead of `bundle_qty`.

Propably the availability of the bundled products will disturb your process, so ensure the products are all salable.

---

I tried it successfully with the sample data of magento and this snippet

```
$client = new \SoapClient('magentoinstallation/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl');
$session = $client->login('testuser', 'password');

$products = array(
    array(
        "product_id"    => 158,
        "qty"           => "1",
        "bundle_option" => array(
            1               => 2, // 1 is the option id, 2 is the bundle/selection id
        ),
    )
);

$cart = $client->call($session, 'cart.create', array('default'));
$resultCartProductsAdd = $client->call($session, "cart_product.add", array($cart, $products));
```

---

I retried my answer and found an important point to recognize.

**SELECT A STORE** ;-)

Just use

`$cart = $client->call($session, 'cart.create', array('default'));`

instead of

`$cart = $client->call($session, 'cart.create');`

(for more details please check the API specs: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cart/cart.create.html)

After changing this, it was simple to add any bundle product, how described above

Comment: Hey, thanks for this, I will test it asap! didn't know about the bundle_option_qty requirement.

Comment: @adamS: I updated my post, just try it with selection of a store, like described above ;-)

Comment: I have tried this but still getting the same issue (Please specify product option(s)). I am not getting how to get the 2 is the bundle/selection id. Can you please help.

Comment: Please add a suggestion about the `bundle_option_qty` as the poster has it wrong too. The arrays there are the OptionID => Qty, not SelectionID => Qty. E.g `"bundle_option_qty" => array("18194" => "1")`